# Accept only https in URL regex pattern c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I got a task for URL validation in which url should not contain any special characters and it should accept only https. I tried with

```
^((https)://)?([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\\/\.\:]*)?$
```

this regex pattern it works fine for special characters but not working for https, Its accepting http also whereas i need it to accept only https. I googled it but unable to find any solution.

Comment: That's because this part: `((https)://)?`means that it is optional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `regex` actually a requirement ?

Actually, it's far more simple (and I guess, efficient) to test for the first 7 characters :

```
    var tests = new String[]{
        "http://shouldfail",
        "https://shouldsucceed",
        "ftp://fail"
    };
    
    foreach(var test in tests){
        if(test.StartsWith("https://", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)){
            Console.WriteLine(test + " is OK");
        }else{
            Console.WriteLine(test + " is not OK");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this for example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pattern = @"^(https:\/\/)[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$";
    Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
    string[] urls = { "https://test.com", "http://test.com" };

    foreach (var item in urls)
    {
        var test = reg.IsMatch(item);
        Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Result is:

```
True
False
```